# how to add a div box near message component in react-chat-elements messagelist

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this very simple chat component: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-zhukovsky-5x5882?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { MessageList } from "react-chat-elements"
import "react-chat-elements/dist/main.css";
import "./style.css"; //.width400 {width: 400px;}

function child() {
  //height should be 100% of the message
  return (
    <div style={{ "width": "7px", "height": "20px", "border": "1px solid black", "background-color": "red", "position": "relative", "display": "flex" }}></div>
  );
}

export function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MessageList
        className='message-list width400'
        lockable={true}
        toBottomHeight={'100%'}
        dataSource={[
          {
            position: "left",
            type: "text",
            title: "Kursat",
            text: "This is a long message that should have a long element near it. This is a long message that should have a long element near it",
          },
          {
            position: "right",
            type: "text",
            title: "Emre",
            text: "That's short",
          },
        ]}
        children={[child(), child()]}
        isShowChild={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm using `MessageList` component imported from `react-chat-elements` and documented [here](https://detaysoft.github.io/docs-react-chat-elements/docs/messagelist)
I want to add a box div near each message as shown in the image, but I can't a straightforward solution of doing so.[image]
I tried to add children, isShowChild properties to the component with the values `[child(), child()]` and `{true}` it didn't work as expected

Comment: Please update your question with code IN the question so we may best assist you here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss isn't the sandbox working? updated anyway

Comment: Why I made the comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/139898  Also for React folks this is useful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/125981